# PHP/Codeigniter - add multiple images anywhere inside a text

Tags: php, codeigniter

What i want to do is to create a add/edit articles with multiple images, like a blog.
Now, lets say that in my add_article page/view i have a form with: an input type="text", a textarea, 3 input type="file" (for 3 different photos) and a submit button.

Is there any way that i can insert those images anywhere i want inside the text?

Comment: Well, all i have so far is the add_article view and the model that inserts that data into the database (except for the images, which i'm working on now). I was hoping for some logic steps or something :)

Comment: if the text is rendered as hmtl, you can try adding `<img src="PATH"` where PATH is the uploaded image path in server. but can't you use something like CKEditor which provides more functionality?

Comment: thanks. i will try with CKEditor to see if it fits my needs:)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like what you're trying to achieve is when you add an article you want the opportunity to be able to upload up to 3 images and in the textarea specify where you want these images to be displayed.

This could easily be achieved using the php function [vsprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php). Where ever you want to place an image you just add `%s` in the textarea. Just make sure that `%s` isn't being escaped and that the number of `%s` match with number of images.

Example for output:

```
$body = 'Image #1: %s<br />
    Image #2: %s<br />
    Image #3: %s';

$images = array('<img src="img1.jpg" />', 
    '<img src="img2.jpg" />', 
    '<img src="img3.jpg" />'
);
echo vsprintf($body, $images);
```

Comment: Here is what i did eventually:

Anywhere in the textarea where i want the images i write the extra image id like this: {21}, where 21 is an image id.
Than, foreach extra image, i use `str_replace({id}, <img src="blabla.jpg" />, $textarea)` and it works like a charm. If you need more info, just say something :)